# How to allow subtypes to have methods with stricter parameter requirements

Tags: scala, types, monads, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to implement Monads in Scala, and came across a problem which I don't know if it's possible to solve:

The example code is (doesn't compile, just for reference):

```
trait Monad[A]
{
    def pure(value : A) : Monad[A]
    def flatMap[B](func : A => Monad[B]) : Monad[B]
}

trait State[S, A] extends Monad[A] with Function1[S, (A, S)]
{
    override def pure(value : A) : State[S, A] = new State[S,A]() {
        def apply(state : S) = (value, state)
    }

    override def flatMap[B](func : A => State[S, B]) : State[S, B] = 
      new State[S, B]() {
         def apply(state : S) =
         {
            val first = State.this.apply(state)
            func.apply(first._1).apply(first._2)
         }
    }
}
```

My problem is in the method

```
def flatMap[B](func : A => Monad[B]) : Monad[B]
```

I want it defined in such a way that when a trait inherits Monad, (for example State), then the method would be

```
def flatMap[B](func : A => State[S, B]) : State[S, B]
```

I other words, I want to know if it's possible to define a method in a trait in such a way that it enforces the parameter to be a *subtype* of the current type.

Comment: You need [F-Bounded polymorphism](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded).

Comment: Monad traits usually use higher kinded types, as seen [here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monad.scala#L11). You may need a seperate `Monad` trait for monads with more than one type parameter. Or use make use of path dependant types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO monad interfaces need to be high-order type-constructors, like type-class (and implicit conversion for monad instances):

```
trait Monad[C[_]] { // monad for category C
  def pure[A](x : A): C[A]
  def flatMap[A, B](func : A => C[B]) : C[A] => C[B]
}
```

But if you prefer to use monad features by extending Monad interface then I can propose some fixes for your code:

```
trait Monad[A] {
  type M[x] <: Monad[x]

  def pure(value : A) : M[A]
  def flatMap[B](func : A => M[B]) : M[B]
}

trait State[S, A] extends Monad[A] with Function1[S, (A, S)] {
  type M[x] = State[S, x]

    override def pure(value : A) : M[A] = new State[S,A]() {
        def apply(state : S) = (value, state)
    }

    override def flatMap[B](func : A => M[B]) : M[B] = 
      new State[S, B]() {
         def apply(state : S) = {
            val first = State.this.apply(state)
            func.apply(first._1).apply(first._2)
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Scalaz does implement Monad as a typeclass, but I was just trying to do it "Object Oriented" and came across this problem. I tried doing the same as above (before your answer), but instead of type M[x] = State[S, x] I did M[_] = State[S, _]. Do you know why the second case doesn't work?

Comment: The second case doesn't work, because underscore means any type parameter, so the two types denoted by the underscores in the second case are not related.